# How to find (offline) perl documentation - "case insensitive" or with regular expression

Tags: perl, perldoc

How do I get information from perldoc (offline) when I don't know the exact syntax? 
For example, when searching for the "lwp" module, it's not sufficient to look for `perldoc -m lwp` or `perldoc -m lwp::simple` (in linux/unix). 
As a beginner I would think, perl would provide something like `perldoc -m /lwp/` to search for the explression.
But you have to find out the exact syntax of the module, and then you can search for the documentation (or, you would write a oneliner/grep to search all the pod files for the expression) - but sometimes I don't remember the exact syntax and need a hint.
Do I miss something? 
Searching the faq can be done with an expression `perldoc -q something` but not anything else (-f / -m / ...) ?
Thank you, for your support.

**Update:** 
- ***Windows***: (by its case-insensitive nature) one can run `perldoc [-m] lwp::simple` and will find *LWP::Simple*
- ***Linux/Unix***: perldoc has an `-i` Parameter for **i**nsensitive search. (see `perldoc -h`) 
Running `perldoc -i [-m] lwp::simple` will find *LWP::Simple*

(the -m Parameter displays the module code and plaintext POD documentation - one can leave it, because it's not that pretty)

Comment: why you are using `-f`

Comment: first you need to tell the module and `-f` check the function in the second parameter and also there is no case sensitive.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo - neither -f nor -m work with expressions or keywords

Comment: You could extend App::perlfind or Pod::Cpandoc to make them case-insensitive.

Comment: It works on Windows because file and folder names are case-insensitive for Windows. Both FAT as well as NTFS do not care about the case. Linux filesystems do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By exact syntax, do you mean the name of the module? Why are you looking for documentation for a module you don't know the name of?

If you want to find some module names installed locally, cpan(1) will give you the list:

```
 % cpan -l
```

From that, you can search a name all you like (as you mentioned):

```
 % cpan -l | grep -i lwp
```

This follows the basic unix idea of reusing tools that already do a good job. `cpan` give you the list and `grep` searches it.

In that list would be LWP. Since module names are case sensitive, you have to use the proper case (although some case-insensitive file systems fake this for you):

```
 % perldoc LWP
```

Mostly, I get the name of the module I want to read about because it's noted in source code or I'm using an object of that type. I take the names from that:

```
print "The object is of type: ", ref $obj;
```

Beyond that, there is current work (discussed this week at The Perl Conference) to index various types of data and let you search for them.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. thats what I need - I did not think about grepping cpan gut it's obvious, yes. Thanks, awesome.
Why would I want this? Sometimes I think "oh, it was a module with something with lwp in its name" ... - and now I would grep the cpanlist and find "oh, yeah, LWP::UserAgent, thats what I want..." (or something like that). -- 
(But, like I wrote - perldoc can indead search case insensitive with`-i` e.g. on linux). My main motivation is to not depend on an online search engine to find documentation about something.